# php sqlsrv_query not return all data

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

The data is an example.

ExampleData table

column count : 30 (int, NVARCHAR(100), NVARCHAR(60), TINYINT ...)

row count : 4000 (index 1~4000)

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ExampleData';
$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

if ( $query === false) return null;

$i = 0;
do
{
 $j = 0;
 while ($row  = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) )
 {
  $result[$i][$j] = $row;
 }
 $i++;
} while ( sqlsrv_next_result($query) )

return $result;
```

$result is not enough data.

return 3000 rows.(index 1~3000)

lose 1000 rows.(index 3001~4000)

It does not return all data.

Is data too big?
Can't I get it all?

Comment: What is the point of calling `sqlsrv_next_result($query)` in the while loop condition supposed to be?

Comment: And what is the ouptut of  `print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)`  (if you place this before the  `return $result;` line)?

Comment: @CBroe Real query returns multiple results. This is an example query.

Comment: @Zhorov `$result['error'] = print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true); ` -> error : ""

Comment: @hayn, try to add `'CharacterSet'=>'UTF-8'` in the `sqlsrv_connect()`, if your data has unicode characters.

Comment: It is normal to have gaps in _ids_. If first id is 1 and last id is 4000 it could mean 4000 rows or 2 rows or anything in between.

Comment: @Zhorov oh!!!!!!! works very well! Thank you!!! very very!!! I wish you a little work and a lot of money!!! thank you!!

Comment: Besides, you're not incrementing $i inside the loop.

Comment: Move `$i++;` inside the inner loop